# How can I remove 'excluded' files from a Git repository?

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, xcode4, repository

**What I'm doing:**

I'm working in Xcode, and started using Git not that long ago.

As per normal, there are some files that I don't want to be included in the Git database, that are to do with Xcode settings. I have already been using a Git repository for a while, but now want to remove these 'editor' files as they are creating problems.

---

**How I'm doing it:**

The proper way to do this is apparently *not* to use a .gitignore. Rather, it is to use .git/info/exclude. By creating a new project in Xcode and selecting the "use Git" option, I was able to find out that the default setting for this should be a .git/info/exclude file of the following:

> .DS_Store
>
> UserInterface.xcuserstate

So I copied this exclude file over to the same git location for the project I'm working on, and it seems to be ok. Except...

---

**What goes wrong:**

The files of course will not be removed/untracked from my current project without manual intervention. So, I've tried the following, which **doesn't** work and tells me there are no such files:

```
git rm --cached .DS_Store
git rm --cached UserInterface.xcuserstate
```

But these files are definitely there, and if I go to commit my repo branch then all sorts of user interface files want to join the party too.

---

**The Question:**

So, what is the 'exclude' file actually doing? Is there a way to make the exclude file untrack  or apply itself to all repo branches easily?

If not, how can I get my project into the same state that it would be had I created the git repo from Xcode at square one?

Comment: Why do you say `.gitignore` is the wrong way to exclude files?  I've always used it with no problems.  Also, I generally try to stay away from the .git dir, there are usually better ways to accomplish things with git.

Comment: The way Xcode creates git repos, it doesn't use a .gitignore. Read the bottom of http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for why an exclude file is more correct.

Comment: Yeah, I just found that.. it's not wrong to use .gitignore... just not the best for ignoring these sorts of files... I mainly use vim for my projects, so I don't have a whole lot of editor files to ignore, and I wasn't aware of the exclude file stuff.

Comment: @AdamWagner thanks, there's a chance that I may be sharing the project with someone in the future, so if I can do it without using .gitignore it would make things a bit cleaner, that's all :)

Comment: Unless the person you're sharing it with is already a pro git user, then not doing it via .gitignore sounds like an invitation to give them the same problems you're having.  While .gitignore can be included in the repo and solve everyone's XCode problems, this .git/info/exclude file is only going to fix it for you.  Is that cleaner?

Comment: True - I was just going by what that github said and trying to replicate the way that Xcode set up a git project. I guess that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason that the first `git rm --cached` command you quoted would fail is that `.DS_Store` is a directory.  Try:

```
git rm -r --cached .DS_Store
```

... instead.  You might also want to check with `git ls-files` that there are actually files within that directory being tracked in the repository.  If there weren't then that would also explain you getting an error.  Check that you're getting case of those files exactly right as well.

(These are generally useful exclude rules that I would add to `.gitignore`, incidentally.)

To answer your other question:

> So, what is the 'exclude' file actually doing? Is there a way to make the exclude file untrack or apply itself to all repo branches easily?

If files are already being tracked in the repository, you will still need to manually unstage them, regardless of whether they're being ignored / excluded.  Essentially, the various places you can add exclude rules all have [the same syntax and semantics](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitignore.html).  The priority of those rules is also described in that documentation, but essentially:

- Exclude rules provided on the command line have highest priority.
- Then `.gitignore` files, starting from the current directory and going up to the top level.
- Then `.git/info/exclude` is used.
- Finally, the lowest priority rules may be in a file specified by the config option `core.excludesfile`.